# Filter product with array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, filter

I'm trying to filter app products with subject,I do this with ajax 
send subjects array to controller,and in controller trying to get products with this code:

```
for($j=1;$j <=sizeof($request->subjects);$j++) 
{
 $product_id= Productsubject::where('subject', $request->subjects[$j - 1])- 
 >pluck('product_id');
 $products = Product::whereIn('id',$product_id)->get();
}
echo $products;
```

When I run,i just give product with latest object of subject array,
for example my subject is`[art,math]` I give just product with math subject,How I can give all products with art and math subject?

Comment: Are you trying to get products that have both art and math or products that have either art or math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('subjects', function($query) {
    $query-> whereIn('subject', $request->get('subjects'));
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running a new query and overwriting products on every iteration of your loop.

You're using whereIn for your second query.  Why not use it for both and forgo the loop?

```
$productIds = Productsubject::whereIn('subject', $request->subjects)->pluck('product_id');
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->get();
```

Comment: I test it,But get this Error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` where is wrong?

Comment: @HanieAsemi debug $request->subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Devon's answer is definitely the easiest method, but if you wanted you could also use a subquery:

```
Product::whereIn('id', function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->select('id')->from('product_subjects')->whereIn('subject', $request->subjects)
})->get();
```